# Discrepancy using du -hs * command in Unix in subfolders

Tags: unix, memory-management, diskspace, du

Ciao,
I have the following problem.

When I use the command **du -hs foldername** I can see that the folder I am analysing has a size of 80Gb.

[image]

But if use **cd foldername** and rerun the script (or the code **ls -lah** to see the details of each file) I can not find files that justify that size.

[image]

Can you explain me why?

How can I find the files/folder that more than anyone contribute to the 80Gb?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `*` doesn't include files/directories with names that start with a dot.

Instead of using `du -sh *`, use `du -ah -d 1`. It will start at the current directory, instead of taking a list of files/directories from the commandline. `-a` tells it to include files as well as directories, and `-d 1` tells it to list down to a "maximum depth" of 1, i.e. show files in the current directory, and show the totals for subdirectories of the current directory, but don't show a detailed list of everything in those subdirectories.